# How to form a JSON request for Jackson global Polymorphic Deserialization?

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jackson

Jackson allows Polymorphic Deserialization: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Specifically, I am trying to use Global default typing with:

```
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

Documentation specifies that request

> ..is included, using default inclusion mechanism (additional wrapper
>   array in JSON).

but I do not understand what exactly that means. I am not sure how to actually form the JSON request that specifies the subtype being sent. I tried the following three requests with no success so far:

```
{
    "com.package.MySubType" : {
        "name": "someName" 
    }
}

[
    "com.package.MySubType",
    {
       "name": "someName" 
    }
]

{
    "@type" : "MySubType",
    "name": "someName"
}
```

I am checking for instance type using `instanceof` and it always fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/nhZAn4TSHG4

```
[ "com.foobar.MyType", { "property1" : 2, "property2" : "foo" } }
```

Altho I decided to go the property route on the end because it seems more logical.